# HTML response for HTTP Post

Tags: json

We are posting data to a URL (https://website/rest/v2/executions) using an orchestration tool, which should return a number from the website.  Data used to post is in json format.  Occassionally we receive a html response instead of number.  Header used in data is application/json. Validated json data, and it is fine.  Below is the error, can someone help in identifying the cause?

HTML Response:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Operations Orchestration</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


<link href="/oo/features/theme/css/oo-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript">
//this is a workaround to a defect in the glorious ie,
// apparently it throws an exception if we try to write to the console and the console is not open...
if (!window.console) {
window.console = {
log : function (obj) { /*do nothing here since the console is closed*/
}
};
};
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="modal login-container container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span5">
<img src = "/oo/features/theme/images/mfLogo-flat-200x26.png" style="margin-left:20px;"/>
</div>

<div class="container span8">
<div>
<div id="header" class="header-login" style="margin-left: 20px">Operations Orchestration</div>

<div class="modal-body form-container">
<div id="logout_label">A general error has occurred. Contact your administrator for more details.</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So you are posting some data to some url using some tool and receive a "general error". How do you think, anybody could help with that little information.

Comment: @derpirscher - thank you for response.  I have copied the html response being received.  My ask is, what could be the cause that results HTML response when posted json content using http post.

Comment: How would anybody know without further details. It just says "general error"